# WaterMark, Logo and Thumbnail in Azure Media services V3

Tags: azure-media-services

Just curious to know

How to implement Watermark, Logo and Thumbnail in Azure Media services V3? Can some please provide some sample code for same. Regards Hamendra

It works in Azure Media services V2

Comment: I’m afraid Stack Overflow isn’t a website where you can ask professional programmers to go off and come to you with ready-made solutions. Do a little research yourself, and then come back if you have a _specific_ issue. You may also find the [tour](/tour) helpful in telling you what types of questions are acceptable here.

Answer (score 1):

See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/customize-encoder-presets-how-to) for how to generate thumbnails as part of a Job. As pointed out in the other response, the v3 APIs do not support overlays of watermarks/logos.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Many of the advanced Media Services v2 features of the Media Encoder Standard are currently not available in v3. For more information, see [feature gaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/migrate-from-v2-to-v3#feature-gaps-with-respect-to-v2-apis).

The v3 API has the following feature gaps with respect to the v2 API. Closing the gaps is work in progress.
The [Premium Encoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-premium-workflow-encoder-formats) and the legacy [media analytics processors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-analytics-overview) (Azure Media Services Indexer 2 Preview, Face Redactor, etc.) are not accessible via v3.
Customers who wish to migrate from the Media Indexer 1 or 2 preview can immediately use the AudioAnalyzer preset in the v3 API. This new preset contains more features than the older Media Indexer 1 or 2.

Many of the [advanced features of the Media Encoder Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-advanced-encoding-with-mes) in v2 APIs are currently not available in v3, such as:

1. Stitching of Assets
2. Overlays
3. Cropping
4. Thumbnail Sprites
5. Inserting a silent audio track when input has no audio
6. Inserting a video track when input has no video

Live Events with transcoding currently do not support Slate insertion mid-stream and ad marker insertion via API call.